# php function imagecreatetruecolor() wont work

Tags: php, image-processing, image-generation

The PHP function `imagecreatetruecolor()` won't work on my apache server. I used an example from the PHP manual

```
header ('Content-Type: image/png');
ini_set('display_error', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20)
or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Imagemagick and GD where [image: phpinfo gd] [image: phpinfo imagemagick] succesfully installed. 
The output in Firefox browser is in translation something like this:

> The picture can't be shown because it has errors.

Comment: You have a suppressor symbol on it, which is the `@` symbol. Take this away and you will probably get an actual error message.

Comment: ok that's right but looks like not in this case, there is no PHP error message, without @ symbol.

Comment: Just to confirm the code posted works for me so it must be something in your setup. Have you tried saving the image rather than displaying it in the browser? http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

Comment: 'imagejpg()' function looks like equal to  imagepng($im,$path)  i tried this with giving a path but it doesn't work, there is no file output, the output folder is chmod 777